# How to find if the value of the field is an array?

Tags: elasticsearch

By accident i inserted some values inside an index as an array with a single value, instead of inserting it as a single string.

For example:
Instead of inserting `"This string"` i inserted `["This string"]`

I need to find the values that have been inserted in the `["String"]` case so that i can update them the way they should be, the normal `"String"`.

The index mapping for the field is a keyword and i can't really seem to a query that finds the values that are arrays.

I can't really delete the index and start over since there is a lot of data in it.

Let's say the index has this mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i inserted two values

```
PUT <index>/_doc
{
  "url": "google.com"
}

PUT <index>/_doc
{
  "url": ["google.com"]
}
```

How can i find the documents that are like the second document that are an array of a single value?

Note: This is with elasticsearch version 7.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't have a dedicated array data type, so `"string"` and `["string"]` are equivalent.

The following query will find both of your documents.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "url": "google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

So, to be fair, you don't need to do anything unless it matters for the application that would later consume the search results and actually expect a string instead of array.

Comment: Yeah that's my concern. The result will be stored elsewhere that will later be referenced  by the application and is causing some problems. Thank you for the answer though :)

Comment: Guess I'm just gonna have to tweak my application code before storing the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-script-filter.html)

```
GET <index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "params._source.url instanceof List"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the results may vary depending on your elastic version

Comment: Yeah I can't use it in my elasticsearch version since accessing the _source in script seems to be removed in version 6.4. Thank you though :) I'll update my question so that the elasticsearch version is metioned

Comment: I tried switching the `params._source.url` with `doc['url']` but the results are not the ones that are expected. None of the results were inside an array.

Comment: there are [differences](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.14/painless-field-context.html) between `params._source` and `doc`

Comment: Yup, thought I should just give it a try though.